# RXJS Drag n drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, rxjs

This questions relates to RXJS. I'm trying to adapt the drag and drop example in github to work for a class of divs not just a single element ID.
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/dragndrop/dragndrop.html

simple changes to give the div a class nor an ID dont work and i lose ability to drag the element

3 simple changes:

```
HTML line 7 i.e. <div class="dragTarget">Drag Me!</div>
CSS line 1 i.e. .dragTarget { style attributes unchanged }
JS line 4 i.e var dragTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('dragTarget');
```

Im not skilled enough to know if this is a bug in RXJS or that the example is not generalised enough. The documentation on RXJS events suggests these changes should be sufficient. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you missed `[0]` at the end of `var dragTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('dragTarget')` :)

Comment: "The fromEvent method also supports adding event handlers to multiple items, for example a DOM NodeList. This example will add the 'click' to each element in the list". https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/events.md

Comment: post your actual modified code

Comment: Please post your code. It's hard for us to help you this way.If you have specific Rx issues post them instead :)

Answer (score 5):

`fromEvent` will use the `on` and `off` methods of any Object you pass it, otherwise it will use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. So if you're using jQuery, you can simply select all of them and use that (`Observable.fromEvent($('.targetNode'), 'mouseup')` for example).

Otherwise, you can use any object with an `on` and `off` method to subscribe or unsubscribe from the events, like I'm doing below.

Other than that, you can use the `target` property on the `MouseEvent` objects you get in each stream to get the actual DOM node you care to move...

Something like the example below should do the trick.

```js
(function (global) {

  /**
    selectNodes is a method to select a NodeList, but convert it to 
    a type that has `on` and `off` methods RxJS 2 expects to see for `fromEvent`
  */
  function selectNodes(selector) {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    return {
      // the selected nodes
      nodes: [].slice.call(this.nodes),

      // subscribe to an event on every selected node
      on: function(eventName, handler) {
        this.nodes.forEach(function(node) { node.addEventListener(eventName, handler); });
      },

      // unsubscribe from the event on every selected node
      off: function(eventName, handler) {
        this.nodes.forEach(function(node) { node.removeEventListener(eventName, handler); });
      }
    };
  }

  function main () {
    // IMPORTANT CHANGE: Use the selectNodes method we made
    var dragTargets = selectNodes('.dragTarget');

    // Get the three major events
    var mouseup   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTargets, 'mouseup');
    var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,   'mousemove');
    var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTargets, 'mousedown');

    var mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap(function (md) {

      // calculate offsets when mouse down
      var startX = md.offsetX, startY = md.offsetY;

      // Calculate delta with mousemove until mouseup
      return mousemove.map(function (mm) {
        mm.preventDefault();

        return {
          left: mm.clientX - startX,
          top: mm.clientY - startY,
          target: mm.target, // IMPORTANT CHANGE: the element you care about
        };
      }).takeUntil(mouseup);
    });

    // Update position
    var subscription = mousedrag.subscribe(function (d) {
      d.target.style.top = d.top + 'px';
      d.target.style.left = d.left + 'px';
    });
  }

  main();

}(window));
```